# Writing tail recursive procedure in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to convert the code below into a tail recursive procedure (it takes a number 'n' and a list 'items' and returns the n first items of the list).

```
(define (take n items)
   (if (= 0 n)
       '()
   (if (< (length items) n)
       items
       (cons (car items)
             (take (- n 1) (cdr items))))))
```

I have tried with this code

```
(define (take n items)
  (define (iter-lst n lst)
    (if (null? n)
        lst
        (iter-lst (- n 1) (cdr lst)))
  (iter-lst 0 items)))

(take 4 '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
(define (take1 n items)
  (define (take-it k items res)
    (if (or (null? items) (>= k n))
        (reverse res)
        (take-it (+ k 1) (cdr items) (cons (car items) res))))
  (take-it 0 items '()))
```

This works also if the first parameter is a negative integer.